# How to use a PipedInputStream in a Producer Endpoint in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel to consume a huge (GB) file, process/modify some data in the file and finally forward the modified file via an AWS-S3, FTP or SFTP producer endpoint to its target. In the actual usage scenario using an intermediate(temporary) file holding the processed data is not allowed.

In case of the AWS producer, the `configure` method of the corresponding `RouteBuilder` specifies the route as follows:

```java
from("file:/...")
    .streamCaching()
    .process(new CustomFileProcessor())
    .to("aws-s3://...");
```

In it's `process(Exchange exchange)` method the `CustomFileProcessor` reads the input data from `exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class)` and writes the processed and modified data into a PipedOutputStream.

Now the PipedInputStream connected with this PipedOutputStream should be used as the source for the producer sending the data to AWS-S3.
I tried `exchange.getOut().setBody(thePipedInputStream)` in the `process` method but this doesn't work and seems to create a deadlock.

So what is the correct way - if it is possible at all - of piping the processed output data of the CustomFileProcessor to the producer endpoint so that the entire data is send over?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging into this the solution was quite simple. I only needed to place the pipe reader into a separate thread and the problem was solved.